# Grab and pass dict/JSON associated with string from list

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, printing

I have the following list

```
configuration = ['configuration1A1', 'configuration1B1', 'configuration1C1']
```

Each element of the list is a string

```
>>>type(configurations_new[0])
str
```

If I print each string from the list separately, each has associated with it a dictionary

```
>>>configuration1A1
>>>type(configuration4A3)
dict
```

As I want to pass the dictionary associated with each string, depending on the name associated with an id on the list above, how do I do that?

So far, I have the following

```
uuids[i] = api_client.prediction_build_model_predict(globals()[datasets[idx]], configuration[idx], wait_to_finish = False).request_uuid
```

But the above `configuration[idx]` is picking up the string with the configuration name and not the dictionary associated with that string. It is required to go to the list and pick up the configuration names (the list is sorted according to the usage one intends to give to it, that's why in what one has it picks up the `idx` from the list).

And as it picks the string the request to the API looks like the following

[image]

Instead of

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just add `globals()` in front of `configuration[idx]` do you get the desired output?

```py
uuids[i] = api_client.prediction_build_model_predict(
    globals()[datasets[idx]],
    globals()[configuration[idx]],
    wait_to_finish = False).request_uuid
```

---

Edit 1:

To avoid the `globals()` call you could iterate through the datasets and configurations.  Something like this:

```py
datasets = [dataset1A1, dataset1B1, dataset1C1]
configuration = [configuration1A1, configuration1B1, configuration1C1]
    
for d_set, config in zip(datasets, configuration):
    uuids.append(
        api_client.prediction_build_model_predict(d_set, config, wait_to_finish=False)
        .request_uuid)
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy, I thought I added it at first, but then somehow I may have removed.